# Trying to execute 4 for loops in TestNG

Tags: for-loop, testng

I have a method which invokes a @Test in TestNG. I have a structure:

```
@TestMethod
public void create(){
int a, b,c;
for (a=0; a < something; a++){
for (b=0; b<something; b++){
for (c=0; c< something; c++){
         testCase(a,b,c)
}
}
}
}
@Test
public void testCase(int a, int b, int c){
    process and do something with a,b and c;
}
```

The problem is as @TestMethod is called before each test case a,b and c are set to 0. I want the TestCase to get the new incremented value of a,b and c. Which annotations should I be using for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Dataprovider. Example form the doc:

```
//This method will provide data to any test method that declares that its Data Provider
//is named "test1"
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
   { "Anne", new Integer(37)},
 };
}

//This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the Data Provider
//named "test1"
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String n1, Integer n2) {
 System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
}
```

Doc: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders